# Getting "ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied" while sending mail using Microsoft flow in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have created a flow for sending mails using below condition.

BirthDay(**list column**) values is equal to convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'W. Europe Standard Time', 'dd/MM')

[image]

while running the flow i'm getting below one.

[image]

Mailing format is below one.

[image]

please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think its because, "Expression result" in your 1st image is "false". So it will not execute "If yes" block. instead it will execute "If no" block.

Comment: yes , in "If no" block it is working fine but it need to satisfy the condition. If you have any knowledge on date comparisons in  flows please help.   condition for send mail is : (If Birthday column value = today date then we need to send mail) Currently i'm using this : BirthDay  is equal to convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'W. Europe Standard Time', 'dd/MM')

Comment: See exapmle given [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Compare-dates-Sharepoint-Calendar/m-p/72830) and [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Is-there-an-expression-in-Flow-like-TODAY-in-Excel-that-gives/m-p/83967/highlight/true#M8299).

Comment: Welcome. What is the final formula you used?

Comment: @equals(formatDateTime(items('Apply_to_each')?['BirthDay'], 'YYYY-MM-dd'), formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'YYYY-MM-dd'))

Comment: great. I will summarize this conversation in answer. please accept and upvote so that other users can get help from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting this exception because, "Expression result" in your 1st image is "false". So it will not execute "If yes" block. instead it will execute "If no" block.

In Order to make it execute your "If yes" block and send email to respective user, you need to make the condition from your 1st image to `true`.

Please follow below links to make your condition correct:

1. [Compare dates - Sharepoint Calendar](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Compare-dates-Sharepoint-Calendar/m-p/72830).
2. [Is there an expression in Flow like =TODAY()](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Is-there-an-expression-in-Flow-like-TODAY-in-Excel-that-gives/m-p/83967/highlight/true#M8299).

**Update**(as you corrected formula):

Use below formula for your condtion to check if today is the BirthDay of user.

```
@equals(formatDateTime(items('Apply_to_each')?['BirthDay'], 'YYYY-MM-dd'), formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'YYYY-MM-dd'))
```